# Stop the smooth scroll with mouse wheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, smooth-scrolling

I have this code so that when a URL is clicked, the view will be scrolled to that particular div (same page) smoothly.
However, I have encountered something buggy.

So let say I clicked the URL, and it is now scrolling smoothly to the bottom of the page. However, when I tried to use my mouse wheel to stop the smooth scrolling but it didn't work. Instead, it gives me that kinda buggy look.

Here's the code
Please advice

```
        <script>
        $('a').click(function(e){

            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
            }, 1500);

            return false;
        });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<script>
    $('html, body').bind('mousewheel', function(e){ 
        $(this).stop();
    });

    $('a').click(function(e){
          $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
          }, 1500);

        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @madushak I don't know about the answer is suitable for the question. However it works for one the bug I used to face.

Answer (score 1):

Add event handlers to the `window` for `wheel` and `mousewheel` events, and in their handlers call `$("html, body").stop()`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the issue is that you are not using document ready function.

Try this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () { // <-- this 
    $('a').click(function(e){

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
        }, 1500);

        return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply... But no, I just tried it.. it still doesn't work :(